# Using a $row in a HTML <ahref>

Tags: php

I am trying to create a button, and in the link use data from the row, but using the below prevents the page from loading.

Current code:

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><code>" . $row['OrderNo'] . "</code></td>";
        echo "<td><a href='viewOrder.php?id=' . $row['OrderNo'] . ' class='btn btn-primary'>View Order</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    unset($row);
}
```

Is there an error in the code or is it just not possible to do this?

Comment: Step 1: [Enable error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1438393).

Answer (score 1):

This line was wrong:

```
echo "<td><a href='viewOrder.php?id='" . $row['OrderNo'] . "' class='btn btn-primary'>View Order</a></td>";
```

Mistake of using " and '. 
Because of your comment, this one is probably that what you want:

```
  <?php
    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC)) {

    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><code>" . $row['OrderNo'] . "</code></td>";
        echo "<td><a href='viewOrder.php?id='" . $row['OrderNo'] . "'&class='btn btn-primary'>View Order</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    unset($row);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missused the quotes

```
echo "<td><a href='viewOrder.php?id=" . $row['OrderNo'] . "' class='btn btn-primary'>View Order</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your concatenation isn't right, the echo is surrounded by double quotes, but you try to use single quotes to break out of it.

This works:

```
echo '<td><a href="viewOrder.php?id=' . $row['OrderNo'] . '" class="btn btn-primary">View Order</a></td>';
```

For future debugging, turn errors on:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> > while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC)) {
>
> ```
>     echo "<tr>";
>     echo "<td><code>" . $row['OrderNo'] . "</code></td>";
>     echo "<td><a href='viewOrder.php?id=" . $row['OrderNo'] ."' class='btn btn-primary'>View Order</a></td>";
>     echo "</tr>";
>     unset($row);
>
>   }
> ```